# Mock dao for Unit Testing

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, generics, junit

I want to develop a Mock of my dao class. How can I mock the following method of my GenericDao?  :

```
    public List<T> getList(int max, int p) throws DataAccessException {
    String t= type.getT();
    String sql = "from " + t+ " order by id desc";
    List<T> o= HibernateUtils(type, this.getSession().createQuery(sql).setFirstResult(max* (p- 1)).setMaxResults(max).list());
    return o;
}
```

Something inside this:

```
    @Override
public List<T> getList(int maxResults, int pageNumber) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    //......

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `getList()` and then use the `subList()` method on the result to cut it into pages.

You will want to use `LinkedHashMap` as your map implementation to make sure the order of values doesn't change.

Try this:

```
@Override
public List<T> getListByPage(int maxResults, int pageNumber) {
    List<T> list = getList();

    if( list.size() > maxResults ) {
        list = list.subList( 0, maxResults );
    }

    int start = pageNumber * pageSize;
    int end = Math.min( start + pageSize, list.size() );

    if( list.size() < start ) {
        list = new ArrayList<T>();
    } else {
        list = list.subList( start, end );
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: can you please show me a possible implementation of the getListByPage method? thanks

Comment: The page number is the total number of pages that exists. I did pagiantion in my webapp.

Comment: Sorry, the page number the initial page. I did pagination in my webapp.

Comment: I think this is it. The only thing is that I don't understand the meaning of "pageSize".

Comment: That's the number of items that you want to display per page.

Comment: Ok so I think pageSize should be a constant. Thank you so much :)